# Generate unique int whenever a new object is created

Tags: java

I want to create a class:

```
class Student {
private static int id;
}
```

Each time an object from `Student` is created, it will assign a unique 6 digit ID for that student.

The other related questions I found on Stack Overflow were not that helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Why not tell us your attempts so we can help fix them, and show what questions you consulted...?

Comment: First hint: don't make it static, otherwise ALL students will have the same id.

Comment: How about providing a counter/sequence that gets incremented whenever you need a new id? If it needs to be persistent put it into a database/file/whatever and you're done. What's so hard about it that other questions didn't help? And the 6-digit requirement can be met in different ways, e.g. allowing values up to 999,999 and either start at 100,000 or at 1(or 0) and use a `String` for the leading zeros.

Comment: sorry i was clearly not thinking there, obviously it cannot be static

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `static` method that relies on a `static` `int` field in the Student class.

If you have race condition in `Student` constructor invokations :

```
public class Student {

    private static int currentId = 0;

    private static final int MAX_VAUE_ACCEPTED = 999999;
    private static Object lock = new Object();

    private static int getNewId() {
       synchronized(lock){
          if (currentId > MAX_VAUE_ACCEPTED) {
            // handling the problem because you is over 6 digits
          }
        currentId++;    
        return currentId;
       }
    }
    ...
    private int id;

    public Student(){
      this.id = getNewId();
    }

}
```

If you have not any race conditions, it is the same thing but without the synchronization.

As a side note, if you use a numeric value to store the information, you should do a conversion to a String to render the id if you want to have a representation on 6 digits in all cases. 
Because for example `000001` is not a representation that you have naturally from a number. You would have rather : `1`.
If you need it, you should have a method that makes the conversion to render the id.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an `ID` class that has a `getID` method to return a new 6 digit id every time it's called:

```
class ID {
    private int id = 0;

    private final int max;
    private final String pattern;

    public ID(int digits) {
        this.max = (int) Math.pow(10, (digits));
        this.pattern = "%0" + digits + "d";
    }

    public synchronized String getID() {
        if(!(id < max)) throw new IllegalStateException("Too many IDs");

        return String.format(pattern, id++);
    }
}
```

(Using `String` here for formatting reasons, you don't need to do calculations with an id any ways.)

Then in your `Student` class you can simply create a `static ID`, and call `getID` whenever you need a new id.

```
class Student {
    private static final ID idFactory = new ID(6);
    private final String id = idFactory.getId(); // will always get called for new Student
    ...
}
```

---

However, if a `Student` object is garbage collected the Id it had will not become available again. You could implement that too, but this will probably be enough in your case.